# How do I constantly monitor if CICS files are open or closed? (Mainframes)

Tags: mainframe, cics

We have a situation where some people accidentally close the online CICS files when the region is up. To counter this,we scheduled a job that will send a mail to the IT team every hour if any file is closed (this job runs once every hour). But it appears that Business needs something that can trigger an alert mail as and when the file is closed, (something to monitor constantly instead of monitoring every hour). Is this feasible through REXX? Or is it possible through any other means? Appreciate any advice you can give me.

Comment: How is it at all possible that you have people "accidentally" closing CICS files in such a way that it affects Business? Stop people doing that. It's easy. Wait till the Auditors find out. Perhaps it is some stage of testing? @david's answer shows the only rational way to go if it is something for some entirely weird reason that you have to allow people to randomly close files to anything which Business people use.

Comment: Well... at times, we will have some adhoc jobs to run in productions that need online files to be closed and its general practice to open it back and some do miss them. Hence we are trying to automate it.

Answer (score 4):

You can trap file close events in real-time using [System Events](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en//SSGMCP_5.3.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.eventprocessing.doc/concepts/dfhep_systemevents.html). CICS has very comprehensive event handling.

Take a look at the [Event Processing Adapter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.3.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.eventprocessing.doc/concepts/dfhep_event_processing_adapters.html) docs. There are many transport methods like MQ, HTTP, TSQ etc. The easiest way to write an event adapter in COBOL would probably be to start a transaction or use a TS queue. If the CICS API supports HTTP client requests you could also use an SMS gateway to to send text alerts which are a little bit more prevalent than e-mails these days.

Comment: Thanks David. Let me check the options.